# Laravel 5.3 - display in validation message which array item does not exist?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I validate an array that comes from the input:

Here are my `rules` and `messages`

```
$rules = [
    'fruits' => [
        'required',
        'array',
        'exists:fruits,id',
    ],
];

$messages = [
    'fruits.required' => 'Fruit is required',
    'fruits.exists' => 'Given Fruit does not exist',
];
```

I pass an array of fruit IDs `"fruits": [11, 2, 844454],` that exist in the database. Validation works. When I provide an ID of non existing fruit (`844454`) I get `Given Fruit does not exist`.

How can I display which ID from a given array does not exist so I could display this in the message.

Like `Given Fruit 844454 does not exist`? or `Given Fruit(s) 844454, 99999, 333333 do not exist`?

Comment: Have you ID in `$request`? OR fruit name?

Comment: I don't care about fruit name (however it's stored in `fruits` table in column `name`. I just want to display invalid IDs in the message. So the answer is no. The only thing about fruits my request has is `"fruits": [11, 2, 844454]`.

Comment: Yes, i know. But my idea is that have you Id or fruit name in request when you validate? If you have Id then you easily do it, if you have an name then find Id using name from that table and add it to message!

Comment: That’s my question mate - how? I don’t want to perform additional queries into DB since the „exists” rule already checked everything.

Comment: I think it's not possible to get those inexist value by `exists` rule. You're likely to create your own rule to make it happen, since `exists` only compare the count found with the input. I might give an answer if you're not being forced in creating rules.

Answer (score 0):

In **Laravel 5.5**, you can create a [Custom Validation Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules) like this:

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ExistsID implements Rule
{
    protected $notExistIDs;
    protected $table;
    protected $column;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($table, $column)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
        $this->column = $column;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string $attribute
     * @param  mixed $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $IDs = DB::table($this->table)->whereIn($this->column, $value)->pluck($this->column)->toArray();
        $this->notExistIDs = array_diff($value, $IDs);

        return count($this->notExistIDs) == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return strtr("Given :table :ids does not exist", [
            ':table' => $this->table,
            ':ids' => json_encode($this->notExistIDs)
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the rules:

```
$rules = [
    'fruits' => [
        'required',
        'array',
        new ExistsID('fruits', 'id')
    ],
];
```

Result:
`Given fruits {\"4\":\"9999\"} does not exist`

The code is [different in Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules) but you can try it with the same idea. Happy coding.